# Rest Template hides SSLHandshakeException

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, resttemplate, sslhandshakeexception

I have two code samples, one which uses Rest Template and other Apache HttpClient to post json to our internal https web service.

We have this known SSL issue on our service load balancer side where server doesn’t respond during handshake, so it is expected that calling clients would fail.

As expected, we get sslhandshakeexception when using Apache HttpClient (4.5.5) but Rest Template (3.1.2) client processes all the requests with no error. Please note that this is one way SSL authentication.

And the strange thing is, if I use HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory to set read time out to any value, I start getting sslhandshakeexception with Rest Template!

But if I set the same read time out with SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory instead then I don't get the exception.

This is confusing as to why Rest Template default behavior would hide SSL Exception.

Please see the code below and let me know if I am missing something.

```
    String result = "";
    try {
        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory clientRequestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
        clientRequestFactory.setReadTimeout(10000);
        final String uri = "{our https url}";
        //Removing clientRequestFactory processes all requests fine
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(clientRequestFactory);
        restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity(input, headers);

        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);

        result = response.getBody().toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        String message = e.getMessage();
        System.out.println("Error: "+message);
    }
    return result;
```

Answer (score 1):

After checking out some Stack Overflow Q&A, it looks like SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory is the default used for Rest template and its read time out is 0 unless set explicitly or through JDK. But the default read time out could make the Http connection unstable and stale. Additionally, this factory is not really well suited for multi-threaded environment. This could explain why SSL Handshake errors (which were intermittent) were ignored.

On the other hand, the thread safe HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory worked "as expected" and returned SSL handshake errors.

(Note: The cause of the SSL error turned out to be some issue with Load balancer SSL Set up.)